# Disable an included appender in logback during tests

Tags: logback

In my logback configuration I have two appenders (for console and logstash).

Each one is defined in a specific file that I include in the main logback.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="console-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="logstash-appender.xml"/>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="io.micronaut" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

In my logback-test.xml I have disable all logging.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <root level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<included>
    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>${LOGSTASH_DESTINATION}</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <message/>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</included>
```

During tests execution, Logback prints some warning complaining about missing properties for logstash, but I want to disable that appender.

```
00:08:13,925 |-ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - No destination was configured. Use <destination> to add one or more destinations to the appender
```

Is there a way to do that?

I tried to use conditional procession with Janino but nothing fix my problem.

Thank for help,

Frank

Comment: Could you share the warnings about missing properties?

Comment: Sure. The problem is related to the LOGSTASH_DESTINATION environment variable.

Comment: looks like you're still using the configuration with `<appender name="LOGSTASH"` and the LOGSTASH_DESTINATION variable is missing?

Comment: yes, but in test i don t have that variable, i don t have the logstash container and i want to disable logging at all too so, for this reason i want to disable that appender but seems, that it reads the logback.xml instead of logback-test.xml.

Comment: how are you building / deploying it? Is the logback-test.xml really present when running? for example if you have it in src/test/resources, it might be removed from the build

Comment: In the next few hours i will share with you a sample repo to replicate this behavior :-)